# Out of box option for displaying Unique view count Over SharePoint Online library document properties page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view, count

We have a SharePoint online site. The default documents library has more than 2000 document. Now client wants to see the unique views count for the respective document he has opened in the DispForm.aspx page.

Is there any out of box option to configure or set the same.

Request you to guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OOTB, you can try activating **SharePoint Viewers** Site Feature, which *Displays to site members the names of people who viewed files or pages on their site*, to see if that meet your requirements.

Site Settings >> Manage Site Features (under Site Actions), and enable the SharePoint Viewers feature

It will show the viewers' information as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. How much time it takes to display the viewer information post feature activation?

Comment: Since I didn't have that many docs in the library in my testing, it was immediate. However, I'm guessing that it might take up to 30 minutes for it to take effect in SharePoint online

Comment: Yes, finally got to see the User count. Thanks for the guidance!